# How to prevent octave taking blank entries as zeroes in csvread?

Tags: plot, octave

I have a csv file containing many x and y columns which I want to plot in a single graph. However the number of data points are different in different columns and those blank values are represented by commas in the CSV file, and Octave is taking them to be (zero,zero).

How to ignore the blanks?

This is such a CSV file (the columns represent x1,y1,x2,y2)

```
0.59,0.09,1.12,0.106
0.23,0.09,0.88,0.104
,,0.02,0.105
```

This is the Octave code

```
function getdata()
M = csvread("filename.csv");
x1 = M(:,1);
y1 = M(:,2);
x2 = M(:,3);
y2 = M(:,4);
figure 1;
plot(x1,y1, "or", x2,y2, "*")
```

This is the plot I get. Note that there is a data point in (0,0), which I don't want.[image]

Comment: Instead you should post some example CSV lines, show your code and result and the wanted result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the help for `csvread`, you'll see that it's just a wrapper for `dlmread`.

> This function is equivalent to
>
> ```
> X = dlmread (FILENAME, "," , DLM_OPT1, ...)
> ```
>
> Any optional arguments are passed directly to 'dlmread'

The `dlmread` help describes an optional parameter `'emptyvalue'` that allows you to specify what is done with an empty entry in the file.

> ```
> -- DATA = dlmread (FILE, SEP, RANGE)
> -- DATA = dlmread (..., "emptyvalue", EMPTYVAL)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The "emptyvalue" option may be used to specify the value used to
>       fill empty fields.  The default is zero.  Note that any non-numeric
>       values, such as text, are also replaced by the "emptyvalue".

Using this parameter, you can insert whatever numerical value you wish. This includes values such as Inf and NaN, which you can use to filter out the data before plotting if that is what you want to do.

```
>> dlmread('testdata.dat')
ans =

   0.59000   0.09000   1.12000   0.10600
   0.23000   0.09000   0.88000   0.10400
   0.00000   0.00000   0.02000   0.10500

>> dlmread('testdata.dat','emptyvalue',999)
ans =

     0.590000     0.090000     1.120000     0.106000
     0.230000     0.090000     0.880000     0.104000
   999.000000   999.000000     0.020000     0.105000

>> dlmread('testdata.dat','emptyvalue',inf)
ans =

   0.590000   0.090000   1.120000   0.106000
   0.230000   0.090000   0.880000   0.104000
        Inf        Inf   0.020000   0.105000

>> dlmread('testdata.dat','emptyvalue',nan)
ans =

   0.590000   0.090000   1.120000   0.106000
   0.230000   0.090000   0.880000   0.104000
        NaN        NaN   0.020000   0.105000
```

It appears that the plot command will ignore both NaN and inf. For this purpose, I'd recommend NaN.

```
>> M = dlmread('testdata.dat','emptyvalue',nan)
M =

   0.590000   0.090000   1.120000   0.106000
   0.230000   0.090000   0.880000   0.104000
        NaN        NaN   0.020000   0.105000

>> x1 = M(:,1); y1 = M(:,2); x2 = M(:,3); y2 = M(:,4);
>> plot(x1,y1,"or", x2,y2,"*")
```

[image: plot with blanks as NaN]

Comment: Inf and NaN are different in a plot. If you plot with lines connecting the points you can see the difference. NaN is not plotted at all, making a gap in the line. Inf is plotted at infinity, making the line go up and out of the plot.